# Convert a list to list of dictionaries in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in Python as follows:

```
result = {"name":"testipgroup",
          "ips": ["10.1.1.7","10.1.1.8"],
          "team_name": "avengers"}
```

The output I need is in this format :

```
result = {"name":"testipgroup",
          "ips": [{"name":"IP_10.1.1.7", "value":"10.1.1.7"}],
          "team_name": "avengers"}
```

My implementation involves popping the 'ips' list from the result dict, iterating over the list, doing transformations and then appending the new list of dicts to the **result** dict as follows:

```
a = result.pop("ips")
result["ips"] = []
for item in a:
    ip_dict = {}
    ip_dict.update({"name": "IP_" + str(item), "value": str(item)})
    result["ips"].append(ip_dict)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this without popping and creating a new array and doing this directly on the **result** dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result['ips'] = [{'name': 'IP_' + i, 'value': i} for i in result['ips']]
```

`result` would become:

```
{'name': 'testipgroup', 'ips': [{'name': 'IP_10.1.1.7', 'value': '10.1.1.7'}, {'name': 'IP_10.1.1.8', 'value': '10.1.1.8'}], 'team_name': 'avengers'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want to map over the list and wrap it in a dictionary, with a few tweaks to it? If so, why don't you try using list comprehension?

```
result['ips'] = [{ 'name':'IP_' + ip, 'value': ip } for ip in result['ips']]
```

Comment: what is the difference between this and the answer which @blhsing gave?

Comment: @Onyambu No difference. I was typing it at the same time but his/her submitted first.